# Prove that $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\geq9abc$ for $a, b, c \geq0.$

Tags: inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Prove that $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\geq9abc$ for $a, b, c \geq0.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By AM-GM $(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}\cdot3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=9abc$

Answer (score 1):

Also we have $(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-9abc=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2abc)=\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0$.